# flutter firebase upload does not working correctly

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

i have  a flutter app with firebase but the firebase dos not working correctly. many times the firebase storage does not work perfectly .the below given is my function to upload files to firebase storage and firebase firestore.some times images and videos will upload but the data to firestore not goes.

```
Future uploadfile({required items}) async {
    try {
      setState(() {
        isloading = true;
      });

      print('Function running');

    

      items.forEach((imageFile) {
        String pathe = DateTime.now().minute.toString();

        final imageName = imageFile.path.split('/').last;
        final file = imageFile;
        final storageRef =
            FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('images');
        final uploadTask = storageRef
            .child(pathe + imageName)
            .putFile(file);

// Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
        uploadTask.snapshotEvents
            .listen((TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
          switch (taskSnapshot.state) {
            case TaskState.running:
              setState(() {
                var progress = 100.0 *
                    (taskSnapshot.bytesTransferred /
                        taskSnapshot.totalBytes);
                isloading = true;
                progress = progress;
              });
              print("Upload is $progress% complete.");
              break;
            case TaskState.paused:
              print("Upload is paused.");
              break;
            case TaskState.canceled:
              print("Upload was canceled");
              break;
            case TaskState.error:
              // Handle unsuccessful uploads
              break;
            case TaskState.success:
              final downloadurl =
                  uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
              images.add(downloadurl.toString());
              print('download url = $downloadurl');
              break;
          }
        });
      });
    } catch (e) {
      'error $e';
    } finally {
      uploadignfund();
    }
  }

  uploadignfund() async {
    if (widget.items.length <= images.length) {
      try {
        print('Uploading data in database');
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('User Posts')
            .add({
          "BookMark": [],
          "Comment List": [],
          "Follow": [],
          "Image": images,
          "caption": captionController.text,
          "Likes": [],
          "Location": widget.location,
          "TimeStamp": Timestamp.now(),
          "Tittle": widget.title,
          "UserEmail": currentuser,
          "Views": 0,
          "description": descriptionController.text
        });
      } catch (e) {
        "error found ${e.toString()} ";
      } finally {
        setState(() {
          downtime = null;
          isloading = false;
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

this is my complete file

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

class CaptionAdd extends StatefulWidget {
  const CaptionAdd(
      {super.key,
      required this.items,
      required this.location,
      required this.title});

  final List<File> items;
  final String title;
  final String location;

  @override
  State<CaptionAdd> createState() => _CaptionAddState();
}

class _CaptionAddState extends State<CaptionAdd> {
  bool isloading = false;
  final progress = 0.0;
  final List<String> images = [];
//function to upload data to database
  final currentuser =
      FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email;
  UploadTask? downtime;
  TextEditingController captionController =
      TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController descriptionController =
      TextEditingController();

  ///upload image to  firebase
  Future uploadfile({required items}) async {
    try {
      setState(() {
        isloading = true;
      });

      print('Function running');

    

      items.forEach((imageFile) {
        String pathe = DateTime.now().minute.toString();

        final imageName = imageFile.path.split('/').last;
        final file = imageFile;
        final storageRef =
            FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('images');
        final uploadTask = storageRef
            .child(pathe + imageName)
            .putFile(file);

// Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
        uploadTask.snapshotEvents
            .listen((TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
          switch (taskSnapshot.state) {
            case TaskState.running:
              setState(() {
                var progress = 100.0 *
                    (taskSnapshot.bytesTransferred /
                        taskSnapshot.totalBytes);
                isloading = true;
                progress = progress;
              });
              print("Upload is $progress% complete.");
              break;
            case TaskState.paused:
              print("Upload is paused.");
              break;
            case TaskState.canceled:
              print("Upload was canceled");
              break;
            case TaskState.error:
              // Handle unsuccessful uploads
              break;
            case TaskState.success:
              final downloadurl =
                  uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
              images.add(downloadurl.toString());
              print('download url = $downloadurl');
              break;
          }
        });
      });
    } catch (e) {
      'error $e';
    } finally {
      uploadignfund();
    }
  }

  uploadignfund() async {
    if (widget.items.length <= images.length) {
      try {
        print('Uploading data in database');
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('User Posts')
            .add({
          "BookMark": [],
          "Comment List": [],
          "Follow": [],
          "Image": images,
          "caption": captionController.text,
          "Likes": [],
          "Location": widget.location,
          "TimeStamp": Timestamp.now(),
          "Tittle": widget.title,
          "UserEmail": currentuser,
          "Views": 0,
          "description": descriptionController.text
        });
      } catch (e) {
        "error found ${e.toString()} ";
      } finally {
        setState(() {
          downtime = null;
          isloading = false;
        });
      }
    }
  }

  // function for uploading it in data base

  final currentUser =
      FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.email;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TaskSnapshot downtime = 0 as TaskSnapshot;
    return Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: SafeArea(
          child: AbsorbPointer(
        absorbing: isloading,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text(
              'Add Description',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black87,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              ),
            ),
            actions: [
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  if (isloading == true) {
                    null;
                  } else {
                    uploadfile(
                      items: widget.items,
                    );
                  }
                },
                child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 7, horizontal: 8),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius:
                          BorderRadius.circular(32),
                      color: Colors.blueAccent,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      isloading
                          ? '  uploading  '
                          : '  Post  ',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white),
                    )),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 6,
              )
            ],
          ),

          //body of the app
          body: CustomScrollView(slivers: [
            SliverAppBar(
              toolbarHeight: 60,
              automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
              title: TextField(
                controller: captionController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Add Caption"),
              ),
            ),
            const SliverFillRemaining(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: 10, horizontal: 15),
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      hintText: "Add Description..."),
                  maxLines: 50,
                  maxLength: 3000,
                  autocorrect: true,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ]),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
            height: isloading ? 51 : 0,
            child: SizedBox(
                child: Stack(
              fit: StackFit.expand,
              children: [
                LinearProgressIndicator(
                  value: progress / 100,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Text(
                      "${progress.roundToDouble()} %",
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white)),
                )
              ],
            )),
          ),
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}

  // items.forEach((imageFile) async {
      //

      //   final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
      //       .ref('images')
      //       .child(pathe + imageName);
      //   print('Storage initialised');

      //   setState(() {
      //     downtime = storageRef.putFile(imageFile);
      //   });
      //   print(
      //       'uploading file ${downtime!.snapshot.bytesTransferred}');

      //   final downloadURL =
      //       await storageRef.getDownloadURL();
      //   print(downloadURL);

      //   images.add(downloadURL);
      //   final snapshot =
      //       await downtime!.whenComplete(() {});
      // });
```

the items required is list of File type:

```
//the files is from file picker plugin 
 files = result.paths
            .map((path) => File(path!))
            .toList();
      });


//this is the push code
Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => CaptionAdd(
                            items: files,
                            location:
                                locationCOntroller.text,
                            title: titleController.text,
                          ))),
```

here is the outpu that i get while tying to upload files

```
I/System.out(28218): [okhttp]:not MMS!
I/System.out(28218): [okhttp]:not Email!
I/System.out(28218): [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
2
I/System.out(28218): [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
I/flutter (28218): Upload is 0.0% complete.
I/flutter (28218): download url = Instance of 'Future<String>'
I/System.out(28218): [okhttp]:check permission begin!
I/System.out(28218): [okhttp]:not MMS!
I/System.out(28218): [okhttp]:not Email!
I/System.out(28218): [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
I/System.out(28218): [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
I/System.out(28218): [okhttp]:check permission begin!
I/System.out(28218): [okhttp]:not MMS!
I/System.out(28218): [okhttp]:not Email!
I/System.out(28218): [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
I/System.out(28218): [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
I/System.out(28218): [okhttp]:check permission begin!
I/System.out(28218): [okhttp]:not MMS!
I/System.out(28218): [okhttp]:not Email!
I/System.out(28218): [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
I/System.out(28218): [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
```

here i am getting the okhttp so much times .
is this is a problem or just for information because it comes so much time before starting the upload as it makes the delay in upload.